# How can i get my process back

Tags: bash, unix, terminal, osx-lion, ps

I accidently closed my terminal window ( iTerm2 ) i am running OSX Lion, i just ran

```
sudo port upgrade outdated
```

and i was hoping i can get the output back on my terminal, the process didn't quit i still see it when i type

```
$ ps -ef | grep upgrade
    0 58525     1   0 11:10AM ??         0:00.04 sudo port upgrade outdated
    0 58535 58525   0 11:10AM ??         0:04.90 /usr/bin/tclsh /opt/local/bin/port
```

What can i do to get it back? i know its going to take a while to finish, am i crazy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You closed the shell that was the parent of your `sudo` command, so it got re-parented to the process `1` the `init`. You have two options:

- Wait till it completes. The `init` will collect its status.
- [`kill(1)`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/kill.1.html) it and then maybe restart your upgrade.

There's no way to attach a terminal to a process orphaned like that.